# How to set Ruby version in Eclim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eclim

I've been trying out eclim with ruby on rails.
When trying to set a hash it shows an error of wrong syntax.

```
exp:

  @update = { 
    title:       "Lorem Ipsum",
    description: "Wibbles are fun!",
    image_url:   "lorem.jpg",
    price:       19.95
  }
```

But when I change the syntax to the old style it runs okay.

```
exp:
  @update = { 
    :title =>       "Lorem Ipsum",
    :description => "Wibbles are fun!",
    :image_url =>   "lorem.jpg",
    :price =>       19.95
  }
```

So how do I set eclim to ruby 1.9.2 ?
Thanks